# how to populate the jasperserver database created from js-install scripts?

Tags: postgresql, war, jasperserver

I am trying to get the Jasper server community edition installed on a Unix serverusing the WAR file distribution. I am using Apache Tomcat 7 as the application server and Postgres as the backend database. I am able to successfully build using the js-install-ce scripts in the buildomatic, but when I try to deploy the war file to the tomcat server I get a bunch of sql exceptions

Upon digging through the logs it looks like the jasperverver database remains empty with no tables created in it. From the documentation I tried to manually create these tables using the js-create.ddl but all sql statements fail while doing so. Is there anything that I am missing? Any  help is appreciated

Comment: could you show us the (error)log?

Comment: Here is the complete log  https://gist.github.com/shruti-palshikar/6340258910969bf82471

Comment: The script doesn't select a database. Maybe there is already a database from a former attempt. do a "drop database jasperserver" and try it again. if that doesn't work look at the script. Maybe you can add a create database / use database.

Comment: My initial thoughts were same so I dropped the database completely and started the process again. If you look at section 5.3 in the documentation where the war file is installed manually I am following those steps. It builds successfully in creating the 'jasperserver' database but fails while populating this database with tables. If you look at the script that script is actually creating tables

Comment: yes it did try to create the tables but fails because it didn't select a database to create the tables in. can you post the script?

Comment: Here is the script thats creating tables https://gist.github.com/shruti-palshikar/2516030e08eb8e91aecb

Comment: try to put a "set search_path = jasperserver;" at the top of it.

Comment: That actually worked! instead of jasperserver I put the schema as 'public'. I see tables created in my database now. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @robin.koch  Are there any configurations needed after the jasperserver is deployed to tomcat? Even after successful creation of tables in the server log it still complains about not finding the tables. Here is the complete log https://gist.github.com/shruti-palshikar/e7b602aaa2252a581be5

Comment: what database is defined in: jasperserver/META-INF/context.xml ? Is it the one you used?

Comment: @robin.koch  When I try to manually run js-ant import-mnimal-ce I get these same kind of errors. I am guessing it is related to some file permissions or like you mentioned the schema isnt defined but I am not able to locate the script thats actually running behind. do u know what script runs while executing this command? Here is the log for reference https://gist.github.com/shruti-palshikar/d3f75f1157028e963a3c

Comment: @robin.koch : Yes, the database is the same in context.xml. BUt it still errors out saying that the relation 'jiresourcefolder' does not exist

Comment: Did you have to change the jasperserverDS-jdbc.xml too?

Comment: I didn't change anything, except for user and password. That's just something I found in Jasper Community. I have no clue what else you could try (except using mysql).

Comment: @robin.koch: I know this is a simple process but I dont know what the issue is, looking at the log can you tell me which script is being executed that errors out? https://gist.github.com/shruti-palshikar/373ee1f2f132f7304b7c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone else trying to get around the issue,

The init-js-db-ce script only tries to create tables without having a search path set.
So in your script please set the path to your jasperserver database.